# Input fieldset with border-radius and shadow not showing all text in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, fieldset

I have the following css:

```
fieldset ul li input {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px white, inset 0 1px 3px #EEE;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px white, inset 0 1px 3px #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px white, inset 0 1px 3px #EEE;
}
```

Which is working under Firefox and Chrome. However in IE9, when I insert some text, I can't see it completely. As you can see is hidden in the half of it:

[image: IE9 fieldset input problem]

Comment: this probably has to do with `line-height` IE has issues with this. Try adding `line-height: 16px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either increase the height or the padding.

```
input {
    padding: 10px;
}
```